# PostgreSQL CREATE TABLE error

Tags: postgresql

I'm new in PostgreSQL. I try to create table in database. In psql i write:

```
CREATE TABLE mail_user (
   user char(50) NOT NULL,
   domain char(50) NOT NULL,
   password char(50) NOT NULL
);
```

But i get error:

**ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user"
LINE 2: user char(50) NOT NULL,
        ^**

What's wrong? How can i fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Just don't use reserved words. It will cause more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use reserved words by quoting them:

```
CREATE TABLE mail_user (
   "user" char(50) NOT NULL,
   domain char(50) NOT NULL,
   password char(50) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: And don't forget to use quotes in every query you execute on this table, "user" will always be a reserved word.

Answer (score 7):

"user" is a reserved word. You may want to try "username" instead. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html